# How can I remove all colors from SVG image?

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I have this SVG image and I need to erase "all" colors, including the white light on front, vest and belly, seeing only the outlines' image. I need it clean to use on a navbar project I'm making. [This is the image I need to edit](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xgvrzo02m9fl95/homerbuddha.svg?dl=0)

Comment: apply a [grayscale filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/grayscale) to the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use a filter to:

1. turn your image into greyscale:

```
<feColorMatrix type="matrix"
                     values="0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
                             0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
                             0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

[image]

2. then use a descrete color transformation to turn black pixels black and everything else white:

```
<feComponentTransfer>
    <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 "></feFuncR>
    <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 "></feFuncG>
    <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 "></feFuncB>
</feComponentTransfer>
```

[image]

3. then inverse all this to have the outline white and everything else black:

```
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="-1  0  0 0 1
                                      0 -1  0 0 1
                                      0  0 -1 0 1
                                      0  0  0 1 0"/>
```

[image]

3. and finally, create a mask from this filtered image and apply it to your image.

```
<mask id="mask" viewBox="0 0 150 206">
    <rect width="150" height="206" fill="black"/>   
    <g filter="url(#nocolor_inv)">
      <!-- your image here -->
      <circle  cx="75" cy="103" r="65" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
    </g>
</mask>
```

[image]
[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 23.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792" xml:space="preserve">
  <filter id="nocolor_inv" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox"
            x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
                     values="0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
                             0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
                             0.33 0.33 0.33 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0"/>
      <feComponentTransfer>
           <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 "></feFuncR>
           <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 "></feFuncG>
           <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 "></feFuncB>
         </feComponentTransfer>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="-1  0  0 0 1
                                                  0 -1  0 0 1
                                                  0  0 -1 0 1
                                                  0  0  0 1 0"/>

    </filter>
  <mask id="mask" viewBox="0 0 150 206">
   <rect width="150" height="206" fill="black"/>
   
      <g filter="url(#nocolor_inv)">
        <!-- your image here -->
        <circle  cx="75" cy="103" r="65" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
      </g>
  </mask>

    <g mask="url(#mask)">
        <!-- your image here -->
        <circle cx="75" cy="103" r="65" fill="red" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: hello @Holger Will, that's a very great answer!; isn't there a way to keep the same sharpness of 2nd image on the 3rd?, looks too much pixelated